# Using Jersey Client inside EJB 3 stateless session bean on Weblogic

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, jersey, weblogic11g

I am using Jersey client inside a EJB 3 stateless session bean. I can deploy the EJB project on Weblogic 11g. But when I try to look up the bean from a JSP, I get the following error

```
 javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client; nested exception is: java.rmi.RemoteException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client
 at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:112)
 at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:91)
 at $Proxy66.sayHelloFromServiceBean(Unknown Source)
 at jsp_servlet.__yelpin._jspService(__yelpin.java:92)
 at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3594)
 at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
 at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2202)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2108)
 at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1432)
 at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
 at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client
 at weblogic.rmi.internal.ServerRequest.sendReceive(ServerRequest.java:205)
 at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:345)
 at weblogic.rmi.cluster.ClusterableRemoteRef.invoke(ClusterableRemoteRef.java:259)
 at com.yelpin.ABCD_xruy6c_ABCDRemoteImpl_1032_WLStub.sayHelloFromServiceBean(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.invoke(RemoteBusinessIntfProxy.java:73)
 ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/Client
 at com.yelpin.ABCD.sayHelloFromServiceBean(ABCD.java:26)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:310)
 at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
 at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
 at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
 at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
 at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
 at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.jee.spi.MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.visit(MethodInvocationVisitorImpl.java:37)
 at weblogic.ejb.container.injection.EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.callback(EnvironmentInterceptorCallbackImpl.java:55)
 at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.jee.spi.EnvironmentInterceptor.invoke(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:50)
 at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
 at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
 at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
 at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
 at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
 at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
 at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
 at $Proxy67.sayHelloFromServiceBean(Unknown Source)
 at com.yelpin.ABCD_xruy6c_ABCDRemoteImpl.sayHelloFromServiceBean(ABCD_xruy6c_ABCDRemoteImpl.java:61)
 at com.yelpin.ABCD_xruy6c_ABCDRemoteImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at weblogic.rmi.internal.ServerRequest.sendReceive(ServerRequest.java:174)
 ... 23 more
```

I am new to EJB 3, Jersey and Weblogic. What I understand is that, the stateless session bean is unable to find the Jersey Client class. Can anyone help me with this ?

I have two projects in OEPE (Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse). One is a EJB 3.0 project which contains the stateless session bean. The other is a dynamic web project which contains the JSP from which I do a JNDI look up to get the stateless session bean. I am using Jersey Client class inside one of the methods in the stateless session bean. This method is invoked from the JSP.

When I check the deployments on the server using Administrator console, there are two deployments. One is an EAR auto generated by OEPE. This EAR corresponds to the dynamic web project. The other deployment is of type EJB.

I also tried adding the jersey jar files to the lib folder under the server and restarted the server. But still, I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the `NoClassDefFoundError` means that the definition of the Jersey `Client` class can't be found and loaded at runtime (it was there at compile time though). So this is very likely a classpath or packaging issue.

Put your Jersey jar in the `APP-INF/lib` directory of the EAR and try again (if it doesn't work, please update your question with the structure of your EAR).

See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13706/libraries.htm#sthref135 and http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13706/classloading.htm for more details.

**Update:** JARs should go in `EarContent/APP-INF/lib` that should have been [automatically created](http://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=998821&tstart=30) but I'm not using OEPE so I can't confirm. Note that according to this [very recent thread](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1026734&tstart=0), there might be a bug in the OEPE publisher that is under investigation (at least under Linux).

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have updated my question with the structure.

Comment: @rboorgapally Do you deploy your application as an EAR?

Comment: The EAR is autogenerated by OEPE

Comment: @rboorgapally Yeah, I understood that after some Googling and updated my answer with what to do theoretically (and some more links).